# Bash Selective replacing of dots

Tags: bash, sed

I have file names in the following format:

```
My.File.d01.h01.txt
My.New.File.d01.h02.txt
My.Another.File.d01.h03.txt
My.Yet.Another.File.d01.h04.txt
File.d01.h05.txt
```

I want to remove the dot between 'd01.h01', 'd01.h02', 'd01.h03', etc.

I imagine I need to use some form of sed, but I need to retain the dXX and hYY values.

Desired output:

```
My.File.d01h01.txt
My.New.File.d01h02.txt
My.Another.File.d01h03.txt
My.Yet.Another.File.d01h04.txt
File.d01h05.txt
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of backreferences:

```
sed -r 's/(\bd[0-9]+)\.(h[0-9]+)/\1\2/' inputfile
```

For your sample input, it'd yield:

```
My.File.d01h01.txt
My.New.File.d01h02.txt
My.Another.File.d01h03.txt
My.Yet.Another.File.d01h04.txt
File.d01h05.txt
```

Either check for a word boundary before `d` or ensure that it's preceded by a `.`:

```
sed -r 's/(\.d[0-9]+)\.(h[0-9]+)/\1\2/' inputfile
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much for a swift reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that may help:

```
awk -F. '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {if ($i~/d[0-9][0-9]/) f=1;printf "%s"(f?"":FS),$i}print FS $NF;f=0}' file
My.File.d01h01.txt
My.New.File.d01h02.txt
My.Another.File.d01h03.txt
My.Yet.Another.File.d01h04.txt
File.d01h05.txt
```